# cassandra pagination: the difference between driver and CQL

Tags: cassandra, pagination, cql

I am reading driver pagination in [here](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/query_paging.html). but CQL also support LIMIT in WHERE clause. Wonder what is the difference between these two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pagination is how much you of your result you work with at a time.

`WHERE` and `LIMIT` are about what is in your result.

Imagine you request all rows where X < 100. This may refer to 1 million different rows. If the client or the server requested all of this at once it would cause a lot of resource pressure. To avoid this the driver is capable of asking for just a few rows at a time. This allows the client and the server to work with a stream of items rather than allocating space for everything up front.

Comment: yes I agree with you @RussS , also to extend you answer its not the same thing if you limit , cause you will get only those records as specified in limit clause . but if using Pagination ( fetchSize) then after you traverse your rows fetched then again automatically next set of rows are fetched where as in case of limit clause you have to query again .