# python-driver pagination not working

Tags: python, cassandra, pagination, driver, cql

I have below code to use cassandra python driver for pagination

I tried both overriding query and set session default_fetch_size. but none of them working, the results always all rows from the table. what am I missing?

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement

# setup
cluster = Cluster(["10.40.10.xxx","10.40.10.xxx","10.40.22.xxx","10.40.22.xxx"])
session = cluster.connect()
session.set_keyspace("ad_realtime")
# session.default_fetch_size = 10

query = "SELECT * from campaign_offset"
statement = SimpleStatement(query, fetch_size=10)
results = session.execute(statement)

for row in results:
   print row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paging in the Python Driver doesn't mean getting only part of your query. It means only getting parts of your query at a time.

Your code

```
for row in results:
   print row
```

Is invoking the paging machinery. Basically this is creating an iterator which only requests `fetch_size` rows at a time out of the resultset defined by your query.

Use `LIMIT` and `WHERE` clauses to restrict your actual result.
[cassandra pagination: the difference between driver and CQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102279/cassandra-pagination-the-difference-between-driver-and-cql/42102629#42102629)

Comment: http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.ResultSet.current_rows

Comment: @RussS: When is the data actually fetched from Cassandra server: 1 or 2?                        
 1. `results = session.execute(statement)`

 2. `for row in results:
   print row`                                                                                                                         If data is fetched from server in batches of fetch size, does this mean the queries are lazily evaluated. If not, does `results = session.execute(statement)` fetches all data from server or its needed to fetch as shown in 2 to get data at client size?

Comment: Both. Execute will fetch the first page. Upon iterating to the end of the page it fetches the next. The query is immediately evaluated but subsequent pages are lazily fetched. The resultset object also has methods for fetching the entire result at once if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the rows of the current page by using `current_rows`, like:

```
for row in results.current_rows:
    print row
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code might help you to fetch the results in a paginated way-

```
def fetch_rows(stmt: Statement, fetch_size: int = 10):
    stmt.fetch_size = fetch_size
    rs: ResultSet = session.execute(stmt)
    has_pages = rs.has_more_pages
    while has_pages:
        yield from rs.current_rows
        print ('-----------------------------------------')
        has_pages = rs.has_more_pages
        rs = session.execute(ps, paging_state=rs.paging_state)

def execute():
    query = "SELECT  col1, col2 FROM my_table WHERE some_partition_key='part_val1' AND some_clustering_col='clus_val1'"
    ps = session.prepare(query)
    for row in fetch_rows(ps, 20):
        print(row)
        # Process the row and perform desired operation
```